# How can I run this query "/(^2$|^2(,)|(,)2(,)|[2]$)/" in Solr?

Tags: regex, database, solr

I've read some article that Solr automatically adds `^` and `$` in a regex query, and to bypass it , one needs to put `.*` and `.*` around the query.

I would like to run this regex query on Solr:

```
/(^2$|^2(,)|(,)2(,)|[2]$)/
```

How can I convert this regex query to Solr + regex query? because currently it does not work in Solr

Comment: Sounds like you've answered your own question?

Comment: No. emodendroket, the query does not work. I can't find any article that discusses on how can I do it on Solr

Comment: Did you try prepending .* and removing $ at the end already then?

Comment: yes I already tried it, do you use Solr @emodendroket?